Munkres Exercise 58.7
In Munkres Exercise 58.7, we have:

Let $A$ be a subspace of $X$; let $j: A \rightarrow X$ be the inclusion map, and let $f: X \rightarrow A$ be a continuous map. Suppose there is a homotopy $H: X \times I \rightarrow X$ between the map $j \circ f$ and the identity map of $X$.
(b) Show that if $H$ maps $A \times I$ into $A$, then $j_*$ is an isomorphism.

My work so far:
Fix a point $a_0 \in A$. We know that $j_*: \pi_1(A, a_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X, a_0)$ is a homomorphism. Moreover, $j \circ f$ is homotopic to $id_X$, which implies that $j_*$ is surjective. The tricky part involves proving that $j_*$ is injective.
Take any $[\gamma_1], [\gamma_2] \in \pi_1(A, a_0)$ such that $j_*([\gamma_1]) = j_*([\gamma_2])$, i.e., $[j \circ \gamma_1] = [j \circ \gamma_2]$. Then, we need to show that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are path homotopic.

Since $[j \circ \gamma_1] = [j \circ \gamma_2]$, we know that $j \circ \gamma_1$ and $j \circ \gamma_2$ are path homotopic so there exists a path homotopy $F: I \times I \rightarrow X$ from $j \circ \gamma_1$ to $j \circ \gamma_2$.
Then, $f \circ F: I \times I \rightarrow A$ is a path homotopy from $f \circ \gamma_1$ to $f \circ \gamma_2$.

From Question from Munkres algebraic topology section 58: retractions, the accepted answer goes to show that $\gamma_1 \simeq_p f \circ \gamma_1$ in $A$, and $\gamma_2 \simeq_p f \circ \gamma_2$ in $A$, then concludes by transitivity of path homotopies that $\gamma_1 \simeq_p \gamma_2$ as needed.

However, to show that $\gamma_1 \simeq_p f \circ \gamma_1$ (likewise for $\gamma_2$), the answer makes use of the homotopy $H(A \times I) \subseteq A$ to say that $f \circ H$ gives the desired homotopy between $\gamma_1$ and $f \circ \gamma_1$ in $A$.

Since $H$ is only a homotopy and not a path homotopy, how are we able to conclude that $\gamma_1$ is path homotopic (and not simply homotopic) to $f \circ \gamma_1$?

Unfortunately your proof does not work.

Surjectivity:
"$j \circ f$ is homotopic to $id_X$, which implies that $j_*$ is surjective." No because you do not know that the homotopy keeps the basepoint $a_0$ fixed.

Injectivity:
"Then, $f \circ F: I \times I \rightarrow A$ is a path homotopy from $f \circ \gamma_1$ to $f \circ \gamma_2$." No, it is a path homotopy from $f \circ j \circ \gamma_1$ to $f \circ j \circ \gamma_2$. But you cannot even expect that $f(j(a_0)) = a_0$ which is the minimal requirement that $f \circ j \circ \gamma_j$ is path homotopic to $\gamma_j$.
Note that you did not use the homotopy $H$ in your proof, so  why should this show that $j_*$ is surjective?


Also the accepted answer to the linked question does not provide a proof:
"So by stitching together three different homotopies between four loops we have found that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are homotopic in $A$." It is remains unclear what this means. As it stands, I cannot see that it proves anything.
So what can be done to give a proof?
Actually the maps $j$ and $f$ are homotopy equivalences. In fact, $j \circ f \simeq id_X$ via $H$. Since $H$ maps $A \times I$ into $A$, we get a homotopy $\bar H : A \times I \to A$ such that $j \circ \bar H  = H \circ (j \times id_I)$. It is a homotopy from $f \circ j$ to $id_A$.
However, $j$ and $f$ are not necessarily pointed homotopy equivalences (which would require that $f \circ j \simeq id_X$ and $j \circ f \simeq id_A$ via basepoint-preserving homotopies).
Anyway, Munkres's Theorem 58.7 applies to show  that $j_*$ is an isomorphism. There is no proof avoiding this theorem.
